# SQL get top 3 values / bottom 3 values with group by and sum

Tags: sql, rdbms

I am working on a restaurant management system. There I have two tables

`order_details(orderId,dishId,createdAt)`

`dishes(id,name,imageUrl)`

My customer wants to see a report top 3 selling items / least selling 3 items by the month

For the moment I did something like this

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
(SELECT 
    SUM(qty) AS qty,
        order_details.dishId,
        MONTHNAME(order_details.createdAt) AS mon,
        dishes.name,
        dishes.imageUrl
FROM
    rms.order_details
INNER JOIN dishes ON order_details.dishId = dishes.id
GROUP BY order_details.dishId , MONTHNAME(order_details.createdAt)) t
ORDER BY t.qty
```

This gives me all the dishes sold count order by qty.

I have to manually filter max 3 records and reject the rest. There should be a SQL way of doing this. How do I do this in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: In case of ms-sql use: [TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  or, in case of MySQL use [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html)

Answer (score 1):

You would use `row_number()` for this purpose.  You don't specify the database you are using, so I am guessing at the appropriate date functions.  I also assume that you mean a month within a year, so you need to take the year into account as well:

```
SELECT ym.*
FROM (SELECT YEAR(od.CreatedAt) as yyyy,
             MONTH(od.createdAt) as mm,
             SUM(qty) AS qty,
             od.dishId, d.name, d.imageUrl,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(od.CreatedAt), MONTH(od.createdAt) ORDER BY SUM(qty) DESC) as seqnum_desc,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(od.CreatedAt), MONTH(od.createdAt) ORDER BY SUM(qty) DESC) as seqnum_asc
      FROM rms.order_details od INNER JOIN
           dishes d
           ON od.dishId = d.id
      GROUP BY YEAR(od.CreatedAt), MONTH(od.CreatedAt), od.dishId
     ) ym
WHERE seqnum_asc <= 3 OR
      seqnum_desc <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the above info i used i combination of group by, order by and limit
as shown below. I hope this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT
t.qty,
t.dishId,
t.month,
d.name,
d.mageUrl
from
(
SELECT 
    od.dishId,
    count(od.dishId) AS 'qty',
    date_format(od.createdAt,'%Y-%m') as 'month'
FROM
    rms.order_details od
    group by date_format(od.createdAt,'%Y-%m'),od.dishId
    order by qty desc
    limit 3) t
 join rms.dishes d on (t.dishId = d.id)
```